# Health prediction system using data mining in j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, expert-system

I want to develop a health prediction system using data mining. Can anyone give me some tips on how to develop it?

The requirement is that when user enter first symptoms then system will check that in how many disease have this same symptoms after that system will give some options related to symptoms so it can differentiate between those disease and can infer what the disease is.

The added component here (and this is where the data mining and prediction portions comes in) is that, when the user enters a symptom, it should also suggest other symptoms that they might also be experiencing. For example, if they have a fever, there is a high probability that they also have chills, so when they enter "fever" it should suggest "chills" as an additional symptom.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused; what's your actual question? What do you mean by "some tips?" Can you be more specific about what you need help with?

Comment: I am not saying that i need the whole code but i don't know to how to develop it, i need some idea that how to move forward. From where should i start.

Comment: It's unclear what you've done so far. Do you have a design? Have you gathered your requirements?

Comment: Are you basically trying to design an expert system or rules engine? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system

Comment: I want to design an expert system

Comment: Yes i have almost complete the design

Comment: What's your design? What do you have outstanding? Also, what do you mean by "predict" the disease and "using data mining?" Using data mining how?

Comment: If you can watch a video on youtube at given link you will get it clearly as i think am not able to make you clear. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pezdf4cbY8

Comment: Can you at least clarify your question to include what you have outstanding? Also, your post seems to conflate two ideas - identification and prediction. Telling me that "there's a 75% chance that you have the flu right now" is very different than saying "there's a 75% chance that you will get the flu within the next two weeks."

Comment: Incidentally, are you working with a SME to develop the rules? (It's not at all trivial to develop the rules themselves; doing so requires significant domain knowledge that's non-trivial to acquire).

Comment: No it is not about to predict future disease. As the user will provide the symptoms system will replies with disease name which has the same symptoms.

Comment: I am a student and i want to do it as my miner project

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "prediction" and "data mining" then. Exactly how does data mining come into this, and what are you predicting? by definition, "prediction" involves a forecast about a *future* event, not an inference about what's the case right now - see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prediction. Also, if all you're doing is taking a list of symptoms and identifying which diseases have those (e.g. colds and the flu both have fatigue as symptoms), I'm not convinced that this requires an expert system - you can do that with a simple database lookup.

Comment: Do you mean that, given one set of symptoms, you infer what other symptoms they might be experiencing? For example, if the user says that they have a fever, you would ask if they also have chills?

Comment: Right and by asking other symptoms system will come to know about the disease and then suggest some name of doctor. If you can help me to make it with only database lookup then it's great for me. Because i just want to do it anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible database design:

[image]

Here's an example of what the data would look like:
[image]
So, basically, this is saying that the symptoms of the flu are fever, chills, and fatigue, but the symptoms of a cold is just "fatigue." (Obviously this isn't all that complete but it's good for illustration).

One person searched for a disease whose symptoms were "fever" and "chills." A second person searched for a disease whose symptoms were just "chills." A third person searched for a disease whose symptoms were "fever" and "fatigue."

Searches would be done with a stored procedure: you input one or more symptoms and it inserts a record of the search into the SearchHistory table and retrieves a list of diseases associated with those.

If you want to calculate the odds of two symptoms going together, you can have a User-Defined Function that calculates the percent of searches that contain both symptoms. For example, if searches 1, 2, and 3 have both "fever" and "chills" as symptoms, but search 4 has "fever" and "fatigue" and search 5 has just "chills," there's obviously a 60% chance that someone who searches for "fever" will also search for "chills."

There's also a 20% chance that someone who searches for "fever" will also search for "fatigue," but in this case the sample is obviously too small to know for sure if that's actually representative. (That's one of the downsides to this design - your predictions will get better over time, but the early predictions might not be too accurate).

The advantage of this is that you don't have to manually enter any data on the odds of any symptoms occurring together, and the system'll "automatically" adapt and improve over time (i.e. your predictions will keep improving as you get more data) depending on what users of your system search on.

The downside, of course, is that you'd only have data on likely co-occurring symptoms once people started using the system, so early users wouldn't get the advantage of having the predictions, and it would take a little while before it was all that accurate at predicting what symptoms are likely to "go together." (Think of the case above where you were predicting a 20% chance of "fever" and "fatigue" going together based only on a single search).

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting that how to developed it

Comment: @Hetaram Can you be more specific about what you're confused about?

Comment: This is a totaly new concept for me. I don't know how to implement it. You have provide some data where you have create two table one for symptoms and other for disease but I have only one table and the attributes are id, name, symptoms, type. So how can I implement it by using this concept

Comment: @Hetaram You *definitely* want to make Symptoms and Disease separate tables; otherwise, you'll end up with a lot of redundant data. Plus, each disease can have an arbitrary number of symptoms.

Comment: OK I have done this but now how to fetch the symptoms after user enter one symptoms to predict the disease